# Perl Use of uninitialized value in substitution

Tags: regex, perl, initialization, substitution

Why is this generating the error:

**Use of uninitialized value $match in substitution (s///) at ...**

```
my $sub = 0;  #added
my $m;  #added

open (FH1, "<FILE1.txt") || die $!;
open (FH2, "<FILE2,txt") || die $!;

my @strings = (<FH2>);  #each line of the file into an array
close FH2 or die $!;

my $here;
while ( my $url = <FH1> ) {
    chomp $url;

    foreach my $sub (@strings) {      
         my $repeat = 1; 
         while ((my $m = $_) =~ s|(?<![/])(?:[/](?![/])[^/]*){$repeat}[^/]*\K|$sub|)  #<-- Error states the error is occurring here
         {

              print "$m\n";   
              $repeat++;    

              push( @{ $here->{$url} }, $m ); 
         }        
    }
}
```

There is definitely something in the files (as I can print each of the lines inside the `foreach` loop) and the regular expression substitution definitely works as it has been tested in its own program before I tried to move it into this program.

**Is it something obvious I'm overlooking?**

Your help would be much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Thanks to **indent your code** properly

Comment: apologies,  thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never assign anything to `$_`.

```
while ((my $match = $_) =~ ...
```

should be

```
while ((my $match = $url) =~ ...
```

Comment: it was something obvious I was overlooking then, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

`$match` is uninitialized, as the error says.  It is set to `$_`, which is uninitialized — you are explicitly providing loop variables (`$url` and `$sub`), so the implicit variable is not initialized in this case.

I assume you mean to `... ($match = $url) =~ s/the subst/.../ ...`

Comment: it was something obvious I was overlooking then, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`@strings` has an uninitialized string. You're trying to use this string (through `$sub`) to substitute the regex. Make sure `@strings` has the data you want.